# Modify font style in title of tikzposter

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzposter

I want to change the font style in `tikzposter` from `\textsc` which has been the default to normal appearance where the caps appear as caps 'A' and small letters appear small 'a'. I sifted through the TeX files in the package and found no place where I could do this. Can you help me adjust this font issue?

There is also another thing I'd like to customise about the poster. When using the rays theme, the colour changes from light blue to dark at the bottom. I'd like the opposite to happen where the colour starts dark at the top and its intensity gradually  at the bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the title, see the description of `\settitle` in the manual. You can copy the example given there and remove `\sc`.

For the colours, I copied the definition of `\definebackgroundstyle{Rays}` from the file `tikzposterBackgroundStyles.tex` and swapped the `top color` and `bottom color`

```
\documentclass{tikzposter} 
\definebackgroundstyle{Rays}{
    \draw[line width=0pt, top color=backgroundcolor!70!black, bottom
    color=backgroundcolor!70] (bottomleft) rectangle (topright);
    %
    \begin{scope}
        \foreach \a in {10,20,...,80}{%
            \draw[backgroundcolor, line width=0.15cm](bottomleft) --
            ($(bottomleft)!1!(bottomleft)+(\a:120)$);%
        }
        \foreach \i in {1,2,...,50}{%
            \begin{scope}[shift={($(rand*60,rand*70)$)}]
                \draw[backgroundcolor!50!, line width=0.1cm] (0,0) circle (4);
            \end{scope}
        }
    \end{scope}
}
\usetheme{Rays}
\title{Something or other}
\author{A Bloke}

\makeatletter
\settitle{ \centering \vbox{
\@titlegraphic \\[\TP@titlegraphictotitledistance] \centering
\color{titlefgcolor} {\bfseries \Huge  \@title \par}
\vspace*{1em}
{\huge \@author \par} \vspace*{1em} {\LARGE \@institute}
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]